# Split tuple to the demanded format in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples

I read a data from sqlite3, and the output is like
`(3252, u'https://www.google.fr/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=python+split+tuple', u'Using the split command in a list - Python', 10)`

So I want to reformat it to a table like:
`table = [["", "number", "url", "title"],
        ["number", 3252],
        ["urls", .....],
        ["title", ....]]`
So, how can I make like this, because the split can't be used for a tuple...Thanks!!

Comment: from what I understand, you want to create dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = ["number", "url", "title"]
table = [zip(keys, tup) for tup in lines if len(tup) == 3]
```

if you want it as dictionaries:

```
table = [dict(zip(keys, tup)) for tup in lines if len(tup) == 3]
```